# autogrow textarea container not resizing according to textarea size

Tags: jquery, autogrow

I have textarea and a DIV container holding that textarea.

```
<div class="holder">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/211204_417552211638405_1828134258_q.jpg">
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <textarea class="grow" row="5" cols="20"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using autogrow plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".grow").autogrow();  
});
```

When textarea resizes according to  contents the container div doesnt expand accordingly.
I tried to add

```
Height: 100%;
```

But that doesnt work, I see its the float property thats causing problem, but i dont know how to make it work with float property.

#### [Demo Here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/8e9TG/10/)

Comment: Are you sure that there a problem? I viewed your example in Google Chrome 23.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the elements within the `div` are both floated, therefore they are not part of the document flow for the browser to calculate the height of the parent. The quick workaround is to set `overflow: hidden` on the parent container.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8e9TG/12/)

Comment: Yes thats the solution. Sorry for asking such simple question but basically i dont know much about css, i am developer, I know only basic css :)